# writng a file path for a login system

Tags: python, tkinter

so i recently asked about, and then created a pretty simple Login system using files. the code basically works by saving your imputed username as a '.txt' file, and then your password is saved in the file. when logging in the code takes your input ( username)and opens the corresponding '.txt' file . the consent of the file is then checked to make sure it matches your password in put and it then allows you to log in.

```
import sys
import os

str1=(ent.get()+".txt")
password=ent3.get()
name1=os.path.abspath(str1)
myfile = open(name1, 'w')
fh=open(str1,'w')
fh.write(password)
fh.close()
window.destroy()
import project.py
```

and the logging in code

```
def logging_in():
u = ent.get()
password=(ent1.get())
file1=open((u)+'.txt','r')
stored=file1.read()
if stored == password:
  window.destroy()
  import mainmenu.py
else:
  print('sorry something went wrong')
```

my question is whether i can save the '.txt' file to a specific path and be able to open it it from the same path. i am relatively new to coding and am aware that it is most likely something very easy that i am missing.
please bear in mind that my code is integrated with tkinter.

Comment: This is an aside, but this screams HACK to me. Are the file systems separate? If you need a password you should also have separate file systems for each user or a user could overwrite that file and then set the password to something they know and gain access to any users information. Just a thought...

Comment: Yes. Research `askdirectory`.

Comment: What do you mean _"whether i can save the '.txt' file to a specific path"_? Of course you can; that path is the first parameter of the `open` function, like `open('/a/specific/path/'+u+'.txt')`. I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: the code is only for a school project and hacking isn't a big issue, login is only to allow access and isn't for security. i just want to write a file path so that the '.txt' files aren't saved in the same folder as the python files.

Comment: @theworstcoder [As Rawing points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389065/writng-a-file-path-for-a-login-system#comment83765873_48389065), you seem to be on the right track already, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: like i said i am new to coding ( 2 months in fact) and i'm not too sure on how to code using files. but i cant find any relevant documents or such on saving and opening file paths with imputed file names.

Comment: I think you need to better specify your question, there should be tens of examples in SO, but I'm still not sure what the issue you're having is.

Comment: HASH THE PASSWORDS!

Comment: so im yet to hash, but i think im almost there with the final parts of this code. i have just run inot one erro

Comment: i am getting an error message saying that a part of my code is required to be a string and not a tuple. any pointers